# Count values in specific position in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "email"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "vote1"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "vote2"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "vote3"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "vote4"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "vote5"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "a@a.a"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "b@b.b"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "c@c.c"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "d@d.d"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "e@e.e"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "E"
  }
}
```

I want to count how many times each value occurs at position `[1]` of each array.

I have tried many things including `array_count_values()`, but this doesn't allow the option to count occurrences in just a certain position of each array. I'm not quite sure how to go about this issue because the array is multidimensional and I have never had to deal with just counting the values at a specific position.

I apologize if the answer to this is blatantly obvious, I've been working on this issue for a few hours but to no avail, but I also am a beginner when it comes to arrays, especially multidimensional. All ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is, you can loop through the array and put the values of `[1]` into another array, and apply `array_count_values` on the resultant array.

```
$a = array();
foreach ($arr as $ar) {
  $a[] = $ar[1];
}
print_r(array_count_values($a));
```

This will give you:

- `vote1`: 1
- `A`: 5

If the above is what you are looking for? If you want a shorter version, you can also use `array_column`.

Comment: Thanks! Would the value of `$arr` be my existent multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

use array_column($array, 1) to get position[1] elements as array; Then use your array_count_values() to count them.

```
<?php
$array = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]];
var_dump(array_count_values ( array_column($array,1) ));
```